# WF4 Goto or Run Activity if a Condition is met

Tags: c#, android-activity, workflow-foundation-4

I have a WF4 with a Sequence of Activities.

1. CalculateTaxesActivity
2. CreateOrderActivity
3. CreditCardAuthorizationActivity
   and 10 more Activities...

I need to not terminate, cancel or abort but to move from the CreditCardAuthorizationActivity to the "SendReply" message at the End of the Workflow if certain conditions are met within the mentioned Activity.

I'm using the Workflow Designer in VS2010.

Thanks!

Comment: How about using either If activity (to exclude steps that you want to jump pas) or modelling it with a Flowchart instead of a sequence?

Comment: The Flowchart seems to be the best approach, anyhow what I'm asking can it still be done? or I'm going overboard with the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't jump to a random activity somewhere else in the workflow.

What you can do however is create a custom Sequence like activity and add logic so it can skip activities or go back and re-execute. It is restricted to its direct children though as each container is responsible for the execution of its childeren.

With a flowchart you can also jump all over the place but you do have to explicitly model things in your workflow, you can't make a switch you didn't program in advance.